# translate from tcsh to bash issue

Tags: bash, gnuplot, tcsh

I'm trying to translate a tcsh script to a bash one. This script invokes gnuplot this way:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
<script commands>
gnuplot << EOF
set terminal png
<other commands>
plot <args>
```

I tried to just modify 'tcsh' to 'bash', but I get "here-document at line x delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')". Why is this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as the error message says: you need to end the here document with the string given when it was begun, in this case, EOF. You can't just use the end of the file to terminate the here doc.

As an example, here's a fragment from a script where I used a here doc:

```
/usr/bin/gnuplot << GPLOT
set terminal png
set output "$3"
set logscale xy
set xlabel "$1"
set ylabel "$2"
plot "tmp2.$$" notitle
GPLOT
```

Since I began the here doc with `GPLOT`, bash looks for `GPLOT` to indicate the end of the here doc.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what it is I'm supposed to do exactly. I actually don't understand the error message, which is why I came here in the first place. Am I supposed to write << EOF at the end of the script ? If so, why is it that it's not required for tcsh ?

Comment: @bob I've edited in an example. As to tcsh, I can only say that it is not required because its creators decided to allow the end of the file to indicate the end of the here doc; I don't know of a technical reason that bash differs, if there even is one.

Comment: I perfer the bash way.  I think it's a simple "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules" sort of thinking...